# React global loading on same page before render next component

Tags: reactjs, react-loadable

In react, I need a bar loading that will appear on the top of the current page until completely render the next requested component. Here is the example what I exactly want, https://www.bd.airtel.com/en

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a bit of libraries available. To match your exact requirement take a look at this [react-top-loading-bar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-top-loading-bar)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import LoadingBar from 'react-top-loading-bar';

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    loadingBarProgress: 0
  }

  add = value => {
    this.setState({
      loadingBarProgress: this.state.loadingBarProgress + value
    })
  }

  complete = () => {
    this.setState({ loadingBarProgress: 100 })
  }

  onLoaderFinished = () => {
    this.setState({ loadingBarProgress: 0 })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <LoadingBar
          progress={this.state.loadingBarProgress}
          height={3}
          color='red'
          onLoaderFinished={() => this.onLoaderFinished()}
        />
        <button onClick={() => this.add(10)}>Add 10</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.add(30)}>Add 30</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.complete()}>Complete</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: You showed me a bar loading with manual actions. But, I am talking about something automated. Suppose, currently I am on the homepage. When I will click on the link of the about page then it will calculate the rendering time of the about page. Also, loading appears based on that time.

Comment: Nothing is automatic, you have to handle your code in such a way you want, you can use life hooks to achieve the same.